# XML transform of multilevel xml with namespace

Tags: xml, xslt-1.0

I have an XML file with multiple child nodes.
I need to copy a node to another node so as to read to excel as easy task (i need not loop into multiple child nodes).

My sample XML is as below.

```
<MultiBlock xmlns="x-schema:ConfigFileSchema.xml">
    <Block>
        <BlockDef>
            <BlockName>Block1</BlockName>
            <EntityName>Block1</EntityName>
            <TemplateName>SYSTEM:template1</TemplateName>
        </BlockDef>
        <Parameters>
            <Parameter>
                <ParamName>PARAM1</ParamName>
                <ParamValue>PARAM1VALUE</ParamValue>
            </Parameter>
            <Parameter>
                <ParamName>PARAM2</ParamName>
                <ParamValue>PARAM2VALUE</ParamValue>
            </Parameter>
            ...
            ...
            <Parameter>
                <ParamName>PARAMn</ParamName>
                <ParamValue>PARAMnVALUE</ParamValue>
            </Parameter>
        </Parameters>
        <EmbBlocks>
            <Block>
                <BlockDef>
                    <BlockName>EMBBLOCK1</BlockName>
                    <EntityName>Block1</EntityName>
                    <TemplateName>SYSTEM:template1</TemplateName>
                </BlockDef>
                <Block>
                    <Parameters>
                        <Parameter>
                            <ParamName>PARAM1</ParamName>
                            <ParamValue>PARAM1VALUE</ParamValue>
                        </Parameter>
                        <Parameter>
                            <ParamName>PARAM2</ParamName>
                            <ParamValue>PARAM2VALUE</ParamValue>
                        </Parameter>
                        ...
                        ...
                        <Parameter>
                            <ParamName>PARAMn</ParamName>
                            <ParamValue>PARAMnVALUE</ParamValue>
                        </Parameter>
                    </Parameters>
                </Block>
            </Block>
            ...
            ...
            <Block>...</Block>
        </EmbBlocks>
    </Block>
</MultiBlock>
```

I want to Copy

1. `BlockName` and `TemplateName`from `MultiBlock\Block\BlockDef\BlockName` and `MultiBlock\Block\BlockDef\TemplateName` to `MultiBlock\Block\Parameters`
2. Respective `BlockName` and `TemplateName`from `MultiBlock\Block\EmbBlocks\Block\BlockDef\BlockName` and `MultiBlock\Block\EmbBlocks\Block\BlockDef\TemplateName` to respective  `MultiBlock\Block\EmbBlocks\Parameters`

I have tried atleast copying the BlockName with the XSL below. But output is blank. I am not able to understand what may be wrong. Please guide me.

```
<?xml version = "1.0" encoding = "UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version ="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">   
<xsl:template match="/">
    <dataroot>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </dataroot>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="/MultiBlock/Block/BlockDef/BlockName">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="/MultiBlock/Block/Parameters">
    <Parameters>
        <BlockName><xsl:value-of select="../../BlockName"/></BlockName>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </Parameters>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Thanks for reading :)

Comment: I added some closing elements to make your XML _well-formed_ and _valid_.

Comment: Thankyou @zx485

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The input XML has a namespace associated to it `x-schema:ConfigFileSchema.xml` which needs to be mapped in the XSL in order to access the elements correctly. The XSLT element should now look like

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:ns0="x-schema:ConfigFileSchema.xml">
```

The XPath for node `<Parameters>` is different when considered in relation to the `<BlockName>` and `<TemplateName>` nodes. Hence this element has to be handled separately using different templates.

Template 1 -> `<Parameters>` immediately inside `<MultiBlock>`

```
<xsl:template match="ns0:MultiBlock/ns0:Block/ns0:Parameters">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="../ns0:BlockDef/ns0:BlockName" />
        <xsl:apply-templates select="../ns0:BlockDef/ns0:TemplateName" />
        <xsl:apply-templates />
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

Template 2 -> `<Parameters>` deep inside of the `<EmbBlocks>`

```
<xsl:template match="ns0:MultiBlock/ns0:Block/ns0:EmbBlocks/ns0:Block/ns0:Block/ns0:Parameters">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="../../ns0:BlockDef/ns0:BlockName" />
        <xsl:apply-templates select="../../ns0:BlockDef/ns0:TemplateName" />
        <xsl:apply-templates />
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

Complete XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:ns0="x-schema:ConfigFileSchema.xml">
    <xsl:output method="xml" />
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*" />

    <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()" />
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="ns0:MultiBlock/ns0:Block/ns0:Parameters">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="../ns0:BlockDef/ns0:BlockName" />
            <xsl:apply-templates select="../ns0:BlockDef/ns0:TemplateName" />
            <xsl:apply-templates />
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="ns0:MultiBlock/ns0:Block/ns0:EmbBlocks/ns0:Block/ns0:Block/ns0:Parameters">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="../../ns0:BlockDef/ns0:BlockName" />
            <xsl:apply-templates select="../../ns0:BlockDef/ns0:TemplateName" />
            <xsl:apply-templates />
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Output

```
<MultiBlock xmlns="x-schema:ConfigFileSchema.xml">
    <Block>
        <BlockDef>
            <BlockName>Block1</BlockName>
            <EntityName>Block1</EntityName>
            <TemplateName>SYSTEM:template1</TemplateName>
        </BlockDef>
        <Parameters>
            <BlockName>Block1</BlockName>
            <TemplateName>SYSTEM:template1</TemplateName>
            <Parameter>
                <ParamName>PARAM1</ParamName>
                <ParamValue>PARAM1VALUE</ParamValue>
            </Parameter>
            <Parameter>
                <ParamName>PARAM2</ParamName>
                <ParamValue>PARAM2VALUE</ParamValue>
            </Parameter>
            <Parameter>
                <ParamName>PARAMn</ParamName>
                <ParamValue>PARAMnVALUE</ParamValue>
            </Parameter>
        </Parameters>
        <EmbBlocks>
            <Block>
                <BlockDef>
                    <BlockName>EMBBLOCK1</BlockName>
                    <EntityName>Block1</EntityName>
                    <TemplateName>SYSTEM:template1</TemplateName>
                </BlockDef>
                <Block>
                    <Parameters>
                        <BlockName>EMBBLOCK1</BlockName>
                        <TemplateName>SYSTEM:template1</TemplateName>
                        <Parameter>
                            <ParamName>PARAM1</ParamName>
                            <ParamValue>PARAM1VALUE</ParamValue>
                        </Parameter>
                        <Parameter>
                            <ParamName>PARAM2</ParamName>
                            <ParamValue>PARAM2VALUE</ParamValue>
                        </Parameter>
                        <Parameter>
                            <ParamName>PARAMn</ParamName>
                            <ParamValue>PARAMnVALUE</ParamValue>
                        </Parameter>
                    </Parameters>
                </Block>
            </Block>
            <Block />
        </EmbBlocks>
    </Block>
</MultiBlock>
```

Comment: Thankyou very much aniket. You solved my problem, I was trying to make it in one template. Thankyou very much.